# Is a spacetime of constant positive curvature just a 4-hypersphere?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, differential-geometry

In discussions of basic cosmological models, I don't see "spacetime of constant positive curvature" described more simply as a "4-hypersphere".  What am I missing?

Comment: It's not spacetime that has constant positive curvature, it's space. That's why everybody talks about 3-spheres. If spacetime was a 4-sphere time would be periodic!

Comment: Also more importantly, due to the hairy ball theorem, a 4-sphere cannot be a spacetime as you would not be able to define a continuous vector field representing the flow of time.

Comment: Javier: couldn't the antipodal points of the 4-sphere be modeled as the beginning and endpoints of time? If so, (and if I'm understanding your point correctly), then there's no worry about periodic time.

Comment: @bmcdanie: no because if the universe was a 4-sphere the dimension would be a loop like the space dimensions i.e. a closed timelike curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are presumably thinking of the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) for a universe with greater than critical density i.e. a closed universe.

We normally use comoving coordinates to describe this, in which case the time coordinate is not curved and at every point along this time coordinate the three spatial coordinates have the topology of a 3-sphere. That is, if we draw a straight line in any direction and continue it indefinitely the line will eventually return to it's starting point.

This isn't a 4-sphere because this is not true of the time dimension. The time dimension starts at the Big Bang and ends at the Big Crunch so it is just a line not a loop. In fact it is geodesically incomplete at both ends since both the Big Bang and Big Crunch are singular points.

Answer (score 0):

There are different descriptions of Spacetime according to General Relativity.

Look at the De-Sitter-Space. It is a mathematical concept of Spacetime with a  positive curvature. It is a submanifold of Minkowski-Space.

there is also an Anti-De-Sitter-Space, which has a negative curvature. It plays a role in some cosmological theories (like Inflation).

The curvature of Space is also addicted to the Hubble Constant and the measured density parameters.

It can not be said much about the global topology of the Universe but it seems as if it is flat.

Comment: I don't think this is right. De Sitter space is not a submanifold of Minkowski space in any natural sense. Both de Sitter space and Minkowski space are space*times* and can be defined in any dimension --- Minkowski space has $R = 0$ whilst de Sitter space has $R > 0$. Secondly, it is de Sitter space, not anti de Sitter space, which plays a role in inflation. Thirdly, whilst you are right that it seems the universe is 'flat', this is completely unrelated to its global topology; you seem to imply the two are linked.

Comment: It is true that De Sitter and Anti De Sitter spaces can be embedded as submanifolds of Minkowski space of appropariate dimension (or its generalization with slightly different signature).

Comment: De Sitter spacetime is defined in $5$ dimensional Minkowski spacetime as a surface of the form $t^2 - u^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 1$ The anti-de Sitter spacetime is defined in a $2$-time plus $3$space with the constraint $t^2 + u^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 1$, where now $u$ is a second time variable.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. But its defining feature is *not* that it can be embedded in a higher-dimensional Minkowski space --- this would suggest that the two spaces were in some sense on different footings, whereas they are entirely analogous (they are both maximally symmetric spacetimes).

Comment: Blazej is right. I also think (teach me if I am wrong) that this fact is used in the holographic principle (related to ads/cft-correspondence).